# For loop leaves blank td in a table

Tags: php

I am calling a for loop to get data from database with this code which is working fine but only with one problem

```
<table class="table" style="color:#000 !important;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <th>Question</th>
      <th>User Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      </<?php

        for ($x = 0; $x <= 30; $x++) {
        ?> <td><?= $info['ans_' . $x]; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <?php

          $sales_quiz = mysqli_query($conn_quiz, "SELECT * FROM `sales_quiz` where `que_no` = '$x'");
          $sales_que = mysqli_fetch_array($sales_quiz); ?>
      <td><?= $sales_que['que']; ?></td>

    <?php }; ?>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The result is first td of 2nd data which is que is blank and for loop start counting it from 2nd row

[image]

I do create a separate for loop for question and answer but then the table becomes broken.

Comment: Is `</<?php` a typo? It needs to be `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need new rows in a table for every loop then you need to add the `tr` within the loop.

Also all `td`s that need to be on the same row has to be within one `tr`.

So remove the extra `<tr>` and bring them inside the loop.

```
<table class="table"
       style="color:#000 !important;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <th>Question</th>
        <th>User Answer</th>
    </tr>


    <?php
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 30; $x++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $info['ans_' . $x]; ?></td>

            <!-- </tr> Remove these-->
            <!-- <tr>-->

            <?php
            $sales_quiz = mysqli_query($conn_quiz, "SELECT * FROM `sales_quiz` where `que_no` = '$x'");
            $sales_que = mysqli_fetch_array($sales_quiz);
            ?>
            <td><?= $sales_que['que']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }  # the semi-colon (;) at the end is unnecessary
    ?>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: after removing them the table looks like the pic i update with your answer

Comment: Looks like what? I mean did it solve the problem? I assume in order to get the question as the first column you will need to rearrange your `<td>`s

Comment: sorry i thaught comment also can add pics

Comment: Your code will put everything on a single `tr`

Comment: i put them in separate tr also but it breaks the table. one more thing its a modal where table is appering

Comment: let me apply your edit and get back to you

Comment: @dave edited to get the `tr` inside the loop

Comment: it worked, pls explain what i did wrong on your answer to make it more clear for other users. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the "</" in the 10th line of your code, before the first `<?php`  . There is any reason for that "</" to be there? From my perspective that creates a empty `<tr></tr>` on the resultant html file, and thats why you have that empty cell on your table. I might be wrong, just check it out and tell me if it works.

Comment: my bad but i removed it still no change

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `</tr><tr>` to after the last `td`, and *probably* swap your `$info['ans_'.$x];` and  `$sales_que['que'];` since it seems like it should go question then answer, and the variable names make me think you are doing answer then question.

```
<table class="table" style="color:#000 !important;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <th>Question</th>
            <th>User Answer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <?php

        for ($x = 0; $x <= 30; $x++) {
            ?> <td><?= $sales_que['que']; ?></td>

            <?php

            $sales_quiz = mysqli_query($conn_quiz, "SELECT * FROM `sales_quiz` where `que_no` = '$x'");
$sales_que = mysqli_fetch_array($sales_quiz); ?>
            <td><?= $info['ans_'.$x]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php }; ?>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes i also find it confusing like i swap the question and answer but shows it backward like answer and then question . dont know why

Comment: after i applied the solution now its working like it should and i do place them correctly and its working good. thanks for your help. have a nice day